# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 40 input samples and 4 target samples

Tags: python, arrays

I'm training a model for a self driving car. The input is an image, and the label is a a Multi-Hot encoder array containing controls [Z,Q,D,M].
If the car is going forward the array will be [1,0,0,0], if going left: [0,1,0,0]

According to the error:

> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as
>   target arrays. Found 40 input samples and 4 target samples.

I can assume that the model is considering each number in the array a single label where the whole array must be a one label.

Here's my code:

```
def train_model(model, save_best, lr, samples_per_epoch, epochs, data_dir, X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid):

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-{epoch:03d}.h5',
                                 monitor='val_loss',
                                 verbose=0,
                                 save_best_only=save_best,
                                 mode='auto')

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(lr=lr))


    model.fit_generator(batch_generator(data_dir, X_train, y_train, BATCH_SIZE, True),
                        samples_per_epoch,
                        epochs,
                        max_q_size=1,
                        validation_data=batch_generator(data_dir, X_valid, y_valid, BATCH_SIZE, False),
                        nb_val_samples=len(X_valid),
                        callbacks=[checkpoint],
                        verbose=1)

def main():
    # get_data()
    data = load_data(DATA_DIR, TEST_SIZE)
    model = nvidia_model(0.5)
    train_model(model, SAVE_BEST, LR, SAMPLES_PER_EPOCH, EPOCHS, DATA_DIR, *data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Code for **batch_generator**

````
def batch_generator(data_dir, image_paths, controls, batch_size, is_training):
    """
    Generate training image give image paths and associated control keys
    """
    images = np.empty([batch_size, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANNELS])
    steers = np.empty(batch_size)
    while True:
        i = 0
        for index in np.random.permutation(image_paths.shape[0]):
            image_path = image_paths[index]
            control = controls[index]

            image = load_image(data_dir, image_path) 

            # add the image and steering angle to the batch
            images[i] = preprocess(image)

            i += 1
            if i == batch_size:
                break

        yield images, control
```
````